# Why is this while loop iterating infinitely?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

This while loop should have terminated when it encountered the *,as parseInt(num[1])=NaN.Bu it keeps on iterating.Whys?

```
 var num=["1","*","2","3","4"]
    var index=4
    var eachop=1;
    
     while((parseInt(num[index]))!=NaN){
                 num[index]=eachop;
                index=index-1;
               console.log(index);
                            
                        }
```

Comment: `anything != NaN` is the same thing as `true`.

Comment: ^ because [`NaN != NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#testing_against_nan) results in `true`. Anything other than `NaN`, for example `8 != NaN` or `undefined != NaN`, will also result in `true`.

Comment: try `!isNaN(parseInt(num[index]))`